# Problema de Tipos DateTime C# + sqlserver

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

Buenas, tengo el siguiente problema. En una base de datos sqlserver, tengo una entidad con campos de fecha (datetime), generé 2 nuevos campos de fecha y actualicé mi modelo desde la base de datos. Los campos se importaron sin problemas, los agrego a la clase correspondiente, y al hacer la query me dice:

> No se puede convertir el tipo System.DateTime? en System.DateTime , Ya
>   existe una conversión explicita

Así están declarados los campos que sí funcionan:

```
 public DateTime FechaCreacion {get;set;}
 public DateTime FechaModif {get;set;}
```

Y los que estoy queriendo Agregar:

```
public DateTime FechaAsign { get; set; }
public DateTime FechaCierre { get; set; }
```

Y mi Query:

```
query = (from q in _conexion.Ticket_Cab where [bla..bla..bla] 
select new Ticket {[bla..bla] FechaCreacion = q.tik_fechacreacion,
FechaModif = q.tik_fechamodif, FechaAsign = q.tik_fechaAsign,
FechaCierre = q.tik_fechaCierre}).ToList();
```

Los últimos dos campos `(q.tik_fechaAsign , q.tik_fechaCierre )` me los subraya en rojo y me arroja el error que cito arriba. ¿Alguien sabe que puede estar pasando?

Comment: Declara los últimos dos campos que mencionas como `DateTime?` en la clase.

Comment: Bien, eso es una solución, ahora estaría necesitando una explicación jajaj. ¿Por qué en los otros 2 campos funciona sin el signo?

Comment: Estoy en ello ;)

Comment: Cuando adicionas los campos nuevos al modelo y ejecutas la migración, se crean en la base de datos con valor por defecto null, por eso tienen que ser Nullables

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tu problema ocurre al asignar un valor de tipo `Nullable<DateTime>` con `DateTime`, actualmente, declaras las fechas de la siguiente forma:

```
public DateTime FechaAsign { get; set; }
public DateTime FechaCierre { get; set; }
```

`DateTime` es un estructura a la que no se puede asignar `null`, creo que pasa lo mismo con cualquier estructura.

Por lo que debes declarar la variable como un valor capaz de recibir `null` por valor y puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma<sup>1</sup>:

```
Nullable<DateTime> FechaAssign { get; set; }
Nullable<DateTime> FechaCierre { get; set; }
```

O bien de la forma *"bonita"*:

```
DateTime? FechaAssign { get; set; }
DateTime? FechaCierre { get; set; }
```

Esto sucede porque en la declaración de la tabla en tu base de datos, la tabla acepta `null` por valor en estos campos.

Si quieres que los campos sean igual que los anteriores, debes procurar agregar la clausula `NOT NULL` en la definición de la tabla en tu base de datos.

Debes tener en cuenta que al tener un tipo `Nullable<T>` en tu clase, no accedes directamente al miembro `DateTime` interno, sino que debes utilizar la propiedad `.Value` del objeto.

Para acceder al valor real del `DateTime` que defines en el query, debes hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
DateTime AlgunSitioDondeUsar = FechaAssign.Value; // Accede al DateTime interno.
```

Sin mencionar que necesitas hacer un chequeo de `null` para comprobar el valor actual del campo.

---

#### Otra Alternativa:

En lugar de alterar la definición de tu clase `Ticket`, puedes simplemente hacer un chequeo en la consulta y debería funcionar perfectamente, con la salvedad de que no tendrás valores `null` en la clase, puedes utilizar un valor como `01/01/1865 00:00:00 AM` para representar un valor falso o `null`.

La consulta quedaría como la siguiente:

```
query = (from q in _conexion.Ticket_Cab 
         where [bla..bla..bla] 
         select new Ticket { [bla..bla] FechaCreacion = q.tik_fechacreacion,
                              FechaModif = q.tik_fechamodif, 
                              FechaAsign = q.tik_fechaAsign ?? DateTime.Parse("01/01/1800"),
                              FechaCierre = q.tik_fechaCierre ?? DateTime.Parse("01/01/1800") }
        ).ToList();
```

Donde `01/01/1800` es la fecha que indica que tu valor es falso o `null`.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Debes hacer `using System;` a la hora de utilizar este método.

Answer (score 4):

En tu base de datos, seguramente pueden ser nulls, lo que ello te lleva a editar:

```
public DateTime? FechaAsign { get; set; }
public DateTime? FechaCierre { get; set; }
```

Y si en caso te lance error en la query

```
FechaAsign = q.tik_fechaAsign.HasValue ? q.tik_fechaAsign.Value : (DateTime?)null
```

La misma jugada la repites en el siguiente campo

```
FechaCierre = q.tik_fechaCierre.HasValue ? q.tik_fechaCierre.Value : (DateTime?)null
```

Answer (score 3):

En donde utilices los datos `q.tik_fechaAsign` y `q.tik_fechaCierre` ponle `.Value` para que quede de la siguiente manera:

```
query = (from q in _conexion.Ticket_Cab where [bla..bla..bla] 
select new Ticket {[bla..bla] FechaCreacion = q.tik_fechacreacion,
FechaModif = q.tik_fechamodif, FechaAsign = q.tik_fechaAsign.Value,
FechaCierre = q.tik_fechaCierre.Value}).ToList();
```

Esto se debe a que `q.tik_fechaAsign` y `q.tik_fechaCierre` están declarados como `DateTime?`, es decir, son `Nullable`, pueden o no contener un valor y al hacer uso de ellos es requerido ponerles el valor con el que estás trabajando.